# github action to run black on specific folder on a push

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to get github actions to format my python code in a specific folder with black on a push but the action is not formatting the files.

Below is my action:

```yaml
name: Format code on push with Black

on: [push]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: psf/black@stable
        with:
         src: './folder_of_files_to_reformat/'
```

am I wrong in thinking that the path of the files to reformat should go in `src:`  line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed what [GitHub Actions integration](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/github_actions.html) mentions:

> You can also configure the arguments passed to Black via `options` (defaults to '`--check --diff`') and `src` (default is '`.`')

```yaml
- uses: psf/black@stable
  with:
    options: "--check --verbose"
    src: "./src"
    jupyter: true
    version: "21.5b1"
```

Make sure your YAML indentation is correct.
Add verbose option to get more details.